# Is the weightlessness in a swimming pool the same as in outer space?

Tags: gravity, astronauts

Astronauts practice the weightlessness of space in a swimming pool. Is this weightlessness the same as in space? Lets ignore the friction with water imagine them to be suspended in liquid helium...).

If we don't take the inertia of water into consideration (friction) isn't your body in the same state (when floating stationary in the water) as my body would be in, say, the ISS? When I am laying on the floor I can feel the floor prssing me up. Floating in water I don't feel nothing pressing me up. It feels like falling to Earth. Which happens in the ISS.

I am not sure if this question is the same as the supposed duplicate. I ask if it is the same and the other question asks about the differences so it already presupposes they are different. But it is not of much importance anymore. I know the answer. Maybe for others it is of importance. If they ask
if it is the same.

Comment: @OrganicMarble That looks like a much more correct answer than the one marked correct below.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No.

Water supports your body by applying pressure to your skin, with a bit higher pressure on the bottom due to being deeper. This supports the body as a whole quite nicely, but all of your insides are subject to the same forces as if you are lying on a very soft mattress under full gravity.

Thus, for example, the heart still needs to exert the same effort in pumping blood up/down your body, gravity still helps you with swallowing if you are upright, etc.

In microgravity/weightlessness in space, everything *actually* weighs zero (while of course retaining the same mass and inertia), so for example the heart has a somewhat easier job of pumping blood around, it becomes quite a chore to swallow and keep it swallowed, and your body's natural blood-pressure regulation keeps on trying to overinflate your head and drain your feet, resulting in rather interesting head congestion, sinus, and puffy eyes.

However:
For training purposes, the zero-g pool training is "good enough".
It does present a reasonable facsimile of the effects of weightlessness on the human body, and for suitably counterweighted tools and equipment simulates weightlessness for them well enough to turn the training into the 3-D environment that will be encountered in space.
It is far from perfect, for example the added inertia of moving against water is very different, but it is much better than training on a flat floor, or suspended from wires.

Comment: +1. The Neutral Buoyancy Lab is not designed to simulate how your mucus behaves in space, it is designed to train how to use tools in space.

Comment: "the heart still needs to exert the same effort in pumping blood up/down your body" - not quite.  The pressure gradient on your body from the water outside of it makes pumping upwards easier.  If you take a ziplock bag full of red dyed water  under water, it does *not* pool at the bottom of the bag.  If you take it out of the water, it does.  You are the ziplock bag, and your blood the fluid inside of you.  (This applies only to the mostly-fluid parts of you, not the gas parts)

Comment: The big difference is that your ears continue to operate normally while diving, and they tell you which way is up, always. Only the vomit comet overcomes this.

Answer (score 7):

There is a quite importand difference:

Your vestibular apparatus (the natural accelerometer in your ears) works in the swimming pool exactly as usual. You are able to tell up and down. You will not get motion sickness.

Other differences include:
Your body is not perfectly homogenous in regard to density, so you will have some equilibrium posture and some torques and other forces trying to force you in the equilibrium posture. You will have to actively counter these effects.

Your buoyancy will depend on your breathing. You will need to exert force in order to inhale an atmospheric air (or use a pressurized diving equipment).

Your tools made of steel will weight almost as much as outside. Drop a wrench and it goes to the bottom.

p.s. you can't swim in liquid helium. You will hit the bottom hard. It is barely denser than the air in some cities...

Comment: Is liquid helium a bit denser as air?

Comment: "The density of liquid helium-4 at its boiling point and a pressure of one atmosphere (101.3 kilopascals) is about 125 g/L (0.125 g/ml), or about 1/8th the density of liquid water."  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_helium)